# How to run case correction on solution?

Tags: .net, vb.net, roslyn

I have a tiny roslyn based application for code formatting of VB.NET/C# projects based on a [sample provided at codeplex](https://roslyn.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Src/Samples/CSharp/FormatSolution/Program.cs). This application is a new version of older code formatter that I developed based on [DTE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.dte.aspx) in which I programmatically run Visual Studio command `Edit.FormatDocument` on every file in a particular solution like this:

```
projectItem.Document.DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.FormatDocument");
```

This is no longer acceptable, therefore I started developing the new version that would perform the same task as FormatDocument command. One of the features of this command in VB.NET source file is that it corrects casing for both keywords and names, e.g.:

- `public` becomes `Public`,
- variable defined as `fooBar` but used as `foobar` => usage changes to `fooBar`
- etc.

First I thought that `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Formatting.Formatter.FormatAsync(...)` alone would do the job but it seems like it only takes care of the whitespaces. Therefore I started looking elsewhere and discovered method `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CaseCorrection.CaseCorrector.CaseCorrectAsync(...)` but the `CaseCorrector` class is unfortunately `internal`. It makes me wonder though, whether it isn't a bug taking into account method `CaseCorrectAsync` being `public`.

Is there a reasonable way to run case correction in my new roslyn based app?

Comment: Regarding whether or not it's a bug: no, very likely it isn't. Many of Roslyn's helpers are `internal` but the team is open to requests to make them `public` after you've demonstrated the need for it. You should probably create an issue on the repo for this though.

Comment: Keep in mind we are [open source](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn), and so  you can easily fork us and make it public for your own tools. But of course, file the bug too.

Comment: @JasonMalinowski If I may have one more question - are there some instructions how to locally build roslyn nuget packages utilizing the modifications (e.g. making CaseCorrector public) I made?

Comment: Not that I know of. I'll send an email to someone who might know internally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct solution really is to use `CaseCorrector` class which was intended to be `public` as per comments in a [roslyn bug report](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/10653). So to address this issue now one has to make `CaseCorrector` public, build roslyn locally and use the modified binaries.

It should be possible to leverage [BuildNuGets.csx script](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/master/build/BuildNuGets.csx) in order to create roslyn nuget packages incorporating your local changes, if needed.